# how to display an image from folder with php?

Tags: php, image, web, upload, directory

Can you guys help me? I am trying to retrieve an image from folder but the image won't showed up.

Here's my code :

I'm using table "article" :

```
id int(100) auto increment, 
title varchar(150), 
imageName varchar(250) -> to store the file name, 
image varchar(250) -> to store the image location address, 
content text
```

Here's my folder structure:

[image]

(artikel_created.php) -> proccess the title, image and content of the article

```
$tit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title']);
$cont = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content']);
$fileName = $_FILES['image']['name']; //get the file name
$fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size']; //get the size
$fileError = $_FILES['image']['error']; //get the error when upload
$tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
?>

<?php include 'admin_header.php'; ?>

<body>
<section class="body">
    <div id="log"></div>
    <div id="artikel_created_panel">
        <?php

        if ($fileSize > 0 || $fileError == 0) { 
            $move = move_uploaded_file($tmp, '../assets/news_image/' . $fileName); 
            if ($move) {
                $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into articles(title, imageName, image, content) VALUES('$tit','$fileName','assets/news_image/$fileName', '$cont')");
                if (!$result) {
                    trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $result - Error: " . mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR);
            }     else {
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Artikel added succesfully";
                    echo "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <a href=../admin/admin_panel.php>Back to admin panel</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

and here's (artikel.php) to display the article

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=$id");
            if (!$qry) {
                trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $qry - Error: " . mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR);
            }

            /*Fetching data from the field "title"*/
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)) {
                echo "<h2>" . $row['title'] . "</h2>";
                echo "<img src=" . $row['image'] . " />";
                echo "<p>" . $row['content'] . "</p>";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Here's the image:

[image]

Can you guys tell me what's wrong with the code please?

Comment: What's the resulting URL being used in the `img` element?  What is the server's response to that request?  Is that really where the file is located?

Comment: Open in browser and check if the url is proper. Also if you are serving images dynamically in php, you need to check for mime-type of image in http headers

Comment: Answer is change `'assets/news_image/$fileName'` in sql query to `'/assets/news_image/$fileName'` that way you are using absolute url rather than relative which is breaking image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems path issue.

I can see that you are inserting image path in table something like `'assets/news_image/$fileName'` but you are uploading image `'../assets/news_image/'`.

Update file path to :-

For absolute path (recommended) :

```
echo "<img src="."/". $row['image'] . " />";
```

or

For relative path:

```
echo "<img src="."../". $row['image'] . " />";
```

Hope this will help you (y).

Comment: Just edit and add absolute url, don't use relative. They always create problem

Comment: @georoot sure (y).

Comment: @georoot i've changed the sql query to VALUES('$tit','$fileName','../assets/news_image/$fileName', and use echo "<img src=" . $row['image'] . " />"; and the image appeared...Thanks guys :D

Comment: @Arnold glad to hear the answer was helpful. FYI just a side note, have a look at MVC architecture because your app structure would be difficult to maintain in future :)

Comment: @georoot model view controller like in CodeIgniter ?

Comment: Exactly, i noticed that you were serving raw php files, that is usually a bad idea it is always better to have a stable framework handle routing and all that stuff. The added benefit is that you can work on core app and the framework will handle a lot of tedious work for you :)

Comment: awesome!! saved time